# Using multiple meanings of the verb "appreciate"

Tags: word-usage

Native English and Marathi speaker here. I was thinking of literal translations where there can be multiple meanings of a certain word.

For the verb appreciate, the most common interpretation is along the lines of recognizing worth. Another meaning is when something inanimate rises in value, such as a stock appreciating. Can it also be used as an operative verb, for eg. "I appreciated the stock by making a great deal" meaning to say that through my action/inaction I raised the value of something?

I've never seen an example of this and it seems wrong intuitively, but I am interested to hear y'alls thoughts.

Comment: Hello, Vrael. What does [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/appreciate) seem to pronounce  about this?

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

When used to mean ***increase in value***, appreciate is an [intransitive verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_verb), and it cannot take a direct object.

From **[OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/appreciate):**

> **appreciate**
>
> [intransitive] to increase in value over a period of time
>
> *Their investments have appreciated over the years.*

Comment: The verb has a typo.